# Get the first and last indices of continuous occurrence of a particular column value of a panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1    col2
 4        A
 5        A
 6        B
 7        B
 8        B
 9        A
 10       A
 11       C
 12       C
 13       C
 14       B
 15       B
```

Now I want to get all start and stop index for each continuous occurrence of B. so the output will be a list and looks like following list,

```
[2,4,10,11]  # first continuous B starts at index 2 and ends at index 4, same for 10,11
```

I could do this using a for loop by comparing the row values, but the execution time will be huge. I am looking for any pandas shortcut or any other method to do it most efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
isB = df['col2'].eq('B')

# isB.shift() & isB.shift(-1)
# mask those B in the middle
mask = isB & (~(isB.shift() & isB.shift(-1)) )

output = list(df.index[mask])
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try use `shift` create the subgroup and then do `agg` `min` + `max`

```
s=df.reset_index().groupby([df.col2, df.col2.shift().ne(df.col2).cumsum()])['index'].agg(['min','max']).loc['B']
      min  max
col2          
2       2    4
5      10   11
```

If you need more info about A and C

```
df.reset_index().groupby([df.col2, df.col2.shift().ne(df.col2).cumsum()])['index'].agg(['min','max'])
           min  max
col2 col2          
A    1       0    1
     3       5    6
B    2       2    4
     5      10   11
C    4       7    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to use rolling mean to exclude Bs in the middle.

```
(
    df.loc[df.col2=='B']
    .reset_index()
    .loc[lambda x: x['index']!=x['index'].rolling(3, center=True).mean()]
    ['index']
)

0     2
2     4
3    10
4    11
```